# Codeigniter controller class

Tags: codeigniter, class, controller

I created codeigniter controller class as follows

```
class Poems extends CI_Controller{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('poem');
}
```

and then created method poem inside the above class as follows

```
function poem($poemID){
 $data['poem']=  $this->poem->get_poem($poemID);
 $this->load->view('poem',$data);
```

}

/***********************************/
for the above controller class I created in the model get_poem() method as follows

```
function get_poem(){
    $this->db->select()->from('poems')->where(array('active'=>1,'poemID'=>$poemID))->order_by('date_added', 'desc');
    $query=  $this->db->get();
    return $query->first_row('array');
}
```

When I run the poems in the browser it works fine...
When I want to load the poem method as poems/poem in the browser the following error appears.

```
error 1: Missing argument 1 for Poems::poem()
error 2:  Undefined variable: poemID
```

How can I fix this errors

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_poem()` in your model is missing an argument.

In the model, use `get_poem($poemID)` like you have in the controller.

The reason being, you're calling the function:

```
get_poem($poemID)
           ^ with an argument
```

However when you actually get to the function in the model, you use this:

```
get_poem()
         ^ without an argument
```

This means that not only will `$poemID` not be a valid variable in the `get_poem` function, but also the function wont run because it's missing an argument.

Sidenote: `poem` doesn't sound or look like a real word anymore after writing this.

Comment: I add the argument to the model part   get_poem($poemID) still the error isn't fixed

Comment: yes, two errors:  Missing argument 1 for Poems::poem() and  Undefined variable: poemID   both in the controllers/poems.php ...

Comment: If you're getting it in the controller, that's because you need to specify a poem ID. Go to your poem controller in your browser and then type `/poemID` where `poemID` is an actual ID of a poem in your database.

Comment: still didn't work i tried as poems/poemID in the browser, but still 404 Page Not Found. this is because i do not have function with poemID in the class(controller) poems.

Comment: Try `poems/poem/poemID` @user3346201

Comment: thank you my brother the errors are fixed but how can I run using poems/poem only without adding poemID

Comment: Either take away the `$poemID` argument for both, or assign `$poemID = 0` or something similar.